# Is “at” or “of” unnecessary in “people his parents’ age”?

Tags: expressions, prepositions

There was the following sentence in Maureen Dawd's article introducing a Denber couple who are catering to marijuana tourists at their inn under the headline, “Now playing in Denver: Reefer Gladness” in New York Times (January 26).

> “There is something not cool about a 22-year-old,” the 31-year-old
> Brown admits, “who has to wait in line for an hour with **people his
> parents’ age**.” Much less his grandparents’ age.”
>
> [[source]](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/01/26/opinion/sunday/dowd-now-playing-in-denver-reefer-gladness.html?hp&rref=opinion&_r=0)

Is “at” or “of” unnecessary in “people his parents’ age”? Is it considered redundant, or even ungrammatical, if we add “at,” “of” or “who are” between ‘people’ and ‘his age’?

Comment: It can be (is) understood. Also, when used, of and at do not mean quite the same, the default implication being who are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortenings in language

children my age, people your age,

Here "children of my age"or "people of your age" or "people having your age"
is shortend and "of" or "having" are generally omitted.

Shortenings are very common in language. We think rather fast so we have to speak in a way
that thinking and speaking have about the same speed.
So formulas that are used very frequently are shortened.
Unfortunately shortenings are no chapter in grammars, but there should be such a chapter to
sharpen the sensibility for shortenings.
Shortenings (omissions, ellipses) are so frequent that one could fill a dictionary with them.
"Good morning" is short for "I wish you a good morning". For practical use that is much too
long. And we are so accustomed to this shortening that we have almost lost the feeling for the omission.

Comment: So "Tom and John are my age" right?

Comment: I fouund the similar case of shortening in Time magazine's article,"The People's Pope" (Dec. 11,2013). It reads;  In 1973, at 36 he (Pope Francis) was named the head of the Society of Jesus in Argentina and the boss of 'Jesuits many years his senior.'

Answer (score 2):

I have never used 'people *at* his parents' age', if that is what you mean. Nor have I heard it used in Britain. 'People *of* his parents age' does get used, but it is perhaps more common, in my estimation to drop the 'of' these days.